# Getting lookup value from MS Access with pyodbc

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a access Database, where some of the cells have been set as lookup to other tabels and this works as it should.

But when I query it from my Python code, I only recieve the number it is placed in the tabel. How do I get the text?

```
conn = pyodbc.connect(r'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, accdb)};DBQ=' + filepath + ';')
cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute("Select Tagname, PV, OUT from PID")

for row in cursor:
            Tagname.append(row[0])
            arrIn.append(row[1])
            arrOut.append(row[2])

return Tagname, arrIn, arrOut
```

I'm using Python 3.7 and pyodbc

regards Mads

Comment: Please provide the Python code for the query (at least).

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the query to make a `JOIN` of the relevant tables. Since you don't describe your database or which columns in the PID table that represents foreign keys, it is hard to give a complete answer. It should look something like this:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT PID.Tagname, PID.PV, PID.OUT FROM PID INNER JOIN some_other_table ON (PID.Tagname=some_other_table.some_id)")
```

You can also lookup `JOIN` queries elsewhere and find a better example representing your needs.

Comment: I dont understand why I have to do the join. This join function is made in the access through the function lookup. I just want the plain text from the cell and the the number where it is placed.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand you. Isn't the plain text you mention in different tables? What do you mean with the join is "made in the access through the function lookup"?

Comment: Okay, I will try to explain it better.

I have my table PID. The column PV is linked to a table called AIN through the function lookup in MS Access. This gives me a drop down menu in PID.PV so I can select the correct text from AIN, but I only gets the row number the text is placed under in AIN.